# Unable to Run IONIC cordova emulator

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, ionic-framework, javac

I am just trying to run my ionic project on android, and have tried both through the default emulator and genymotion but continue to get the same error.  I have double checked that my JAVA_HOME is set and the jdk is up to date, and that the project structure jdk is set to the right location.  Additionally I have removed and re-added the android platform, after updating the version.  And finally I have checked android studio and made sure all of the SDK tools are up to date, but am still getting the below answer, and have been unable to solve the issues with any tutorials i've searched.

below is the error I get when building for android:

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/CustomTabsHelper.java:77: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6

        List<String> packagesSupportingCustomTabs = new ArrayList<>();
                                                                  ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/ServiceConnection.java:32: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
        mConnectionCallback = new WeakReference<>(connectionCallback);
                                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
2 errors
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 
FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


* Try:
Run with 
--stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or 
--debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.502 secs

(node:16040) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: /Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/CustomTabsHelper.java:77: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
        List<String> packagesSupportingCustomTabs = new ArrayList<>();
                                                                  ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
/Users/DrewGelinas/Desktop/lndFinal/platforms/android/src/org/chromium/customtabsclient/shared/ServiceConnection.java:32: error: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.6
        mConnectionCallback = new WeakReference<>(connectionCallback);
                                                ^
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```